# Changing populated DataTable column data types

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a System.Data.DataTable which is populated by reading a CSV file which sets the datatype of each column to string.

I want to append the contents of the DataTable to an existing database table - currently this is done using SqlBulkCopy with the DataTable as the source.

However, the column data types of the DataTable need to be changed to match the schema of the target database table, handling null values.

I am not very familiar with ADO.NET so have been searching for a clean way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot change the `DataType` of a `DataColumn` after populating it with data.  It's not a read-only property, but you will receive an exception at runtime if you attempt to change it after it already has data.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx):

> An exception is generated when changing this property after the column has begun storing data.

So you will have to either ensure the correct column types in the beginning (if possible), or create a new `DataTable` specifically for the import and copy data from the original `DataTable`.

You could also write a custom `IDataReader` class that reads from your `DataTable` and performs just-in-time conversion and pass that to the `SqlBulkCopy` - it would be a lot more efficient, but it's obviously not a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks - I realise I can't change it once populated. What I am looking for is a way of creating a second DataTable with the correct data types and then importing and converting the data from the first DataTable. It is not possible for the first DataTable to use data types other than String unfortunately.

Comment: @TonE: The only way I can think of to do that would be to implement `IDataReader` and use the `DataTable.Load` method - but if you're going to do that, you might as well just use the reader itself for `SqlBulkCopy` instead of creating a second `DataTable`.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. Would it be possible to derive from DataTableReader, and if so do you know which methods I would need to override to provide the type changing functionality? Just trying to gauge if it is plausible given the time constraints.

Comment: @TonE: `DataTableReader` is sealed, so no, you'd have to write one from scratch.  Even if you could subclass it, you'd have to override almost every method anyway, so it'd be easier to just make your own.  Your `IDataReader` implementation would have to define its own list of columns/fields (possibly just a `List<Type>`) and use the `Convert` class on the original string data.  I'm not sure, but I think you'd also have to provide a valid implementation of `GetSchemaTable` in order to make it work with `SqlBulkCopy`... that's the hard part.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't time to implement this at the moment so have modified the CSV reading code to take a typed DataTable and replace error values with null using a FillErrorEventHandler. Could have done this in the first instance really! The custom IDataReader is a good idea though, will try it out in future.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote this generic function to do the job, it works very well for me:

```
public static bool ChangeColumnDataType(DataTable table, string columnname, Type newtype)
{
    if (table.Columns.Contains(columnname) == false)
        return false;

    DataColumn column= table.Columns[columnname];
    if (column.DataType == newtype)
        return true;

    try
    {
        DataColumn newcolumn = new DataColumn("temporary", newtype);
        table.Columns.Add(newcolumn);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                row["temporary"] = Convert.ChangeType(row[columnname], newtype);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        table.Columns.Remove(columnname);
        newcolumn.ColumnName = columnname;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

You can just copy the code and put it in a class(MyClass here) , and use it like this as an example:

```
MyClass.ChangeColumnDataType(table, "GEOST", typeof (int));
```

Comment: The only problem - new column is added at the end of the collection so if, for example, you binding it to a grid with "autogeneratecolumns=true" it's ordinal position will be different

Comment: Corrected that :) And used it in my solution if you don't mind: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/08/02/ado-net-datatable-change-column-datatype-after-table-is-populated-with-data/

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to set the datatypes of the datatable you're filling up.

E.g.:

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable("countries");
    table.Columns.Add("country_code", typeof (string));
    table.Columns.Add("country_name", typeof (string));
    //...
    //Fill table
```

Or you could change the column types if they are compatible:

```
table.Columns["country_code"].DataType = typeof(string);
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I am currently doing but actually populating the second DataTable with the types correctly set is proving difficult. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are populating from csv file then read schema first in datatable then change the datatype of column then populate the table.
Example: I'm using XML file for importing data.

```
       DataSet dstemp = new DataSet();
       dstemp.ReadXmlSchema(@"D:\path of file\filename.xml");
       dstemp.Tables[0].Columns["Student_id"].DataType = typeof(Guid);
       dstemp.ReadXml(@"D:\path of file\filename.xml");
```

I think it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just like "Eddie Monge Jr" or "Gisway" can't get it.

but with the correct column order.

```
public static bool ChangeColumnDataType(DataTable table, string columnname, Type newtype){
    if (table.Columns.Contains(columnname) == false)
        return false;

    DataColumn column = table.Columns[columnname];
    if (column.DataType == newtype)
        return true;

    try{
        DataColumn newcolumn = new DataColumn("temporary", newtype);
        table.Columns.Add(newcolumn);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows){
            try{
                row["temporary"] = Convert.ChangeType(row[columnname], newtype);
            }
            catch{}
        }
        newcolumn.SetOrdinal(column.Ordinal);
        table.Columns.Remove(columnname);
        newcolumn.ColumnName = columnname;
    }
    catch (Exception){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an improved version of [Gisway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394117/gisway)'s/[Yuri Galanter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961695/yuriy-galanter)'s solution, which addresses the following points:

- [Don't eat exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx), fail early
- Retain nullability/`AllowDBNull` of the original column
- Work with the column object directly, no need for the table object as parameter
- Change naming to typical .Net conventions
- Improve docs
- Include a guid in the temporary column name to really avoid collisions
- Refactor to be extension methods

As the project I needed this for is in VB.Net, my solution is written (and tested) in it too, sorry - converting shouldn't be hard though.

```vb
' following methods will be defined in a module, which is why they aren't Shared
' based on https://codecorner.galanter.net/2013/08/02/ado-net-datatable-change-column-datatype-after-table-is-populated-with-data/ 
' and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692087/1200847 

''' <summary> 
''' Converts DataType of a DataTable's column to a new type by creating a copy of the column with the new type and removing the old one. 
''' </summary> 
''' <param name="table">DataTable containing the column</param> 
''' <param name="columnName">Name of the column</param> 
''' <param name="newType">New type of the column</param> 
<Extension()> 
Public Sub ChangeColumnDataType(table As DataTable, columnName As String, newType As Type) 
    If Not table.Columns.Contains(columnName) Then Throw New ArgumentException($"No column of the given table is named ""{columnName}"".") 
    Dim oldCol As DataColumn = table.Columns(columnName) 
    oldCol.ChangeDataType(newType) 
End Sub 

''' <summary> 
''' Converts DataType of a DataTable's column to a new type by creating a copy of the column with the new type and removing the old one. 
''' </summary> 
''' <param name="column">The column whichs type should be changed</param> 
''' <param name="newType">New type of the column</param> 
<Extension()> 
Public Sub ChangeDataType(column As DataColumn, newType As Type) 
    Dim table = column.Table 
    If column.DataType Is newType Then Return 

    Dim tempColName = "temporary-327b8efdb7984e4d82d514230b92a137" 
    Dim newCol As New DataColumn(tempColName, newType) 
    newCol.AllowDBNull = column.AllowDBNull 

    table.Columns.Add(newCol) 
    newCol.SetOrdinal(table.Columns.IndexOf(column)) 

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows 
        row(tempColName) = Convert.ChangeType(row(column), newType) 
    Next 
    table.Columns.Remove(column) 
    newCol.ColumnName = column.ColumnName 
End Sub
```

If you i.e. have an `int` column which really should be a `bool` column, use it like this:

```vb
table.Columns("TrueOrFalse").ChangeDataType(GetType(Boolean))
```

**Important**: As this changes the DataTable you possible want to do this right after loading the data and accept the changes afterwards. This way change tracking, databinding etc. works normally afterwards:

```vb
table.AcceptChanges()
```

---

If the non-nullability of your column isn't configured correctly when loading the data, as it was the case for my Oracle `NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL` column, you may want to insert code like this:

```vb
table.Columns("TrueOrFalse").AllowDBNull = False 
table.Columns("TrueOrFalse").DefaultValue = 0
```